# Image resizing works in HTML img but not CSS class?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Trying to make a basic web page with React and NodeJS. Currently, my rendering returns this:

```
<div className='App'>
                    <link
                        rel="stylesheet"
                        href="./App.css"
                    />
                    <header className='App-header'>
                        <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
                    </header>
                    
                    <div id='Main'>
                        {this.state.statusElement}
                        <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3" onChange={this.onFileChange.bind(this)} required>
                            <Form.Label>Test Data</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="file" />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button variant="outline-primary" onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} >Upload</Button>{' '}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I wanted to resize the image with the className `App-logo` in the CSS stylesheet profile, as such:

```
.App-logo {
height: 100;
pointer-events: none;
width: 100;
}

img {
  max-width: inherit;
  max-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

However, this did nothing. Then I tried `<img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' width="100" height="100" />` and that worked. I'm not sure why this works and the modifying through CSS stylesheet didn't?

Answer (score 2):

If the `img` style comes after `App-logo`, it will override the `App-logo` style with an inherited value from the parent. Also, you should specify a measurement unit type (px, vw, vh, etc...). Try this:

```
.App-logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And leave out the `img` styling that inherits, IF it comes after the `.App-logo` style.

Also the `link` tag should be in the `head` tag of your page. But that is simply the wrong way to link CSS if you're using a react component.

Seeing as your using react, you should use the import statement at the top of your component.

Like this

```
import './App.css';
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't think I have any parent fields in the HTML though?

Also tried this and didn't work...I wonder if my CSS stylesheet linking is in the wrong place? I read that it should go between HEAD fields in HTML but not sure how that applies with React

Comment: @VictorM There's pretty much always a parent. Even the body tag has a parent technically speaking. The parent of your img tag is the header tag in this instance. As to why this isn't working, I would assume you may be correct in that the CSS file isn't linked properly. You can check quite easily in the developer console of your browser.

Comment: Ah, it doesn't seem to be. Do you know how to properly link it?

Comment: @VictorM Edit your question to include the current method you are attempting to use to import the file, along with a description  of your directory structure, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @VictorM did you have any luck?